# Change automatic email new account

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wiki

Using **MediaWiki**, I can't find the file where the text of the new account automatic email is written. I would like to add it some more information. Do you know which file is it? This is the text:

*Someone created an account for your email address on XXXX (https://XXXX) named "XXXX", with password "XXXX".
You should log in and change your password now.
You may ignore this message, if this account was created in error.*

**EDIT**

Just found it. It's a translation key: MediaWiki:Createaccount-text

Comment: You should answer your own question as an actual answer, and mark it correct! :-)

Comment: Sorry, new here! :s

Answer (score 0):

The email text is written in the system message `MediaWiki:Createaccount-text`.